# Filter on hierarchy depth

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a hierarchical data structure I am displaying in the form of a tree map.  To keep the treemap from becoming too busy I've implemented a drill in feature where the user can click into a box and then, ideally, get another level of detail.

To keep the treemap from being to busy and displaying too many levels I've used a filter function

```
.filter(function(d) {
    return d.depth < 3;
})
```

The problem seems to be that when a user clicks into a box and resets the data (and the root node) the filter doesn't reset as well and I'm not getting the nodes below a depth of 3.

Full code and example below:

```js
function makeTreeMap() {

const data1 = {
 "name": "A1",
 "health": 0.521,
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "B1",
   "health": 0.521,
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "B1-C1",
     "health": 0.614,
     "children": [
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D1",
        "health": 0.666,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
            "value": 30,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
            "value": 35,
            "health": 0.5
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E3",
            "value": 20,
            "health": 0.7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D2",
        "health": 0.45,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
            "value": 10,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
            "value": 14,
            "health": 0.1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D3",
        "health": 0.64,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E1",
            "value": 10,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E2",
            "value": 14,
            "health": 0.2
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E3",
            "value": 7,
            "health": 0.7
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E4",
            "value": 9,
            "health": 0.9
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E5",
            "value": 5,
            "health": 0.6
          }
        ]
      },
      {"name": "B1-C1-D4",
       "value": 2,
       "health": 0.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "B1-C2",
   "health": 0.45,
   "children": [
    {"name": "B1-C2-D1",
     "health": 0.45,
     "value": 12}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "B1-C3",
   "health": 0.5,
   "children": [
    {"name": "B1-C3-D1",
     "health": 0.5,
     "value": 10}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
]
}



  let height = 800
  let width  = 1000

  let treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingOuter(16);

    //d3.json("data.json").then(function(data) {

    let update = (d) => {


    let rootNode = d3.hierarchy(d)

    // sum and sort the root node values
    rootNode
      .sum(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
      });

    treemapLayout(rootNode);

    // bind the data to the nodes
    let nodes = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(rootNode.descendants(), function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })

    nodes
      .exit()
      .remove()

    let newNodes = nodes
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      // NEED TO RE_APPLY THE FILTER!!!!!!!
      .filter(function(d) {
        console.log("depth = " + d.depth)
        return d.depth < 3;
      })
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
      })


    newNodes
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
      })
      // drill in on click
      .on('click', function(d) {
        update(d.data)
      })

    // lable the rectangles
    newNodes
      .append('text')
      .attr('dx', 4)
      .attr('dy', 14)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })

    nodes
      .merge(newNodes)
      .filter(function(d) {
        console.log("depth = " + d.depth)
        return d.depth < 5;
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
      })
      .select('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
      })

    }

    update(data1);

  //});

}
```

```css
rect {
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  fill: #484848;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Treemap layout (with labels)</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="treemap.css">

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="simple-treemap.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="makeTreeMap()">
    <svg id="chart" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter the selection **before** appending the elements. Therefore, it should be:

```
let newNodes = nodes
  .enter()
  .filter(function(d) {
    console.log("depth = " + d.depth)
    return d.depth < 3;
  })
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
  });
```

Here is your snippet with that change:

```js
function makeTreeMap() {

  const data1 = {
    "name": "A1",
    "health": 0.521,
    "children": [{
      "name": "B1",
      "health": 0.521,
      "children": [{
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "health": 0.614,
          "children": [{
              "name": "B1-C1-D1",
              "health": 0.666,
              "children": [{
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                  "value": 30,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                  "value": 35,
                  "health": 0.5
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E3",
                  "value": 20,
                  "health": 0.7
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2",
              "health": 0.45,
              "children": [{
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 10,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E2",
                  "value": 14,
                  "health": 0.1
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D3",
              "health": 0.64,
              "children": [{
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E1",
                  "value": 10,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E2",
                  "value": 14,
                  "health": 0.2
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E3",
                  "value": 7,
                  "health": 0.7
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E4",
                  "value": 9,
                  "health": 0.9
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E5",
                  "value": 5,
                  "health": 0.6
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D4",
              "value": 2,
              "health": 0.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "B1-C2",
          "health": 0.45,
          "children": [{
            "name": "B1-C2-D1",
            "health": 0.45,
            "value": 12
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "B1-C3",
          "health": 0.5,
          "children": [{
            "name": "B1-C3-D1",
            "health": 0.5,
            "value": 10
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }



  let height = 800
  let width = 1000

  let treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .paddingOuter(16);

  //d3.json("data.json").then(function(data) {

  let update = (d) => {


    let rootNode = d3.hierarchy(d)

    // sum and sort the root node values
    rootNode
      .sum(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
      });

    treemapLayout(rootNode);

    // bind the data to the nodes
    let nodes = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(rootNode.descendants(), function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })

    nodes
      .exit()
      .remove()

    let newNodes = nodes
      .enter()
      // NEED TO RE_APPLY THE FILTER!!!!!!!
      .filter(function(d) {
        console.log("depth = " + d.depth)
        return d.depth < 3;
      })
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
      })


    newNodes
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
      })
      // drill in on click
      .on('click', function(d) {
        update(d.data)
      })

    // lable the rectangles
    newNodes
      .append('text')
      .attr('dx', 4)
      .attr('dy', 14)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })

    nodes
      .merge(newNodes)
      .filter(function(d) {
        console.log("depth = " + d.depth)
        return d.depth < 5;
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
      })
      .select('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
      })

  }

  update(data1);

  //});

}
```

```css
rect {
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: white;
}

text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  fill: #484848;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Treemap layout (with labels)</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="treemap.css">

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="simple-treemap.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="makeTreeMap()">
  <svg id="chart" />
</body>

</html>
```